# How to Customize Content not over Header and Footer in TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, customization, cell, tcpdf

I already able to set up Header and Footer.

But, my content by writeHTMLCell cannot fit into the page properly, footer is overlay the content.

using A4 size, Header is 35% height; Content is 50% height; and Footer is 15% height.

I do not know how to set the Content's height to be 50% in all page.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is `$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 55);`

Original is `$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);`

Set value in `PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM` will do.

Comment: @ManishJesani I've approved your suggested edit, but you do not need to emphasis fluff, you should instead remove it.